# WPF button click needs to refresh a binding; how do I do this?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have a button:

```
<Button Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Command="commands:Commands.BuyComponentCommand" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=inventory, Path=SelectedItem}" Click="btnBuy_Click">Buy</Button>
```

And a list box:

```
<ListBox Name="inventory" ItemsSource="{Binding Inventory}">
    ...
</ListBox>
```

And some labels I want to refresh the visibility of when the button is clicked; here's one of them:

```
<TextBlock Name="txtMineralsWarning" Foreground="Yellow" Text="You don't have enough minerals to buy this component." DataContext="{Binding ElementName=inventory, Path=SelectedItem}" Visibility="{Binding Converter={StaticResource NotEnoughMineralsToVisibilityConverter}}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
```

Now the problem is, the labels refresh their visibility when I select a different item in the `ListBox`; however they don't refresh their visibility when I click the button, even though clicking the button can affect the state that determines whether or not the labels should be visible in my converter.

Here's my converter's Convert method, in case it helps:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    var comp = (Component)value;
    if (comp == null)
        return Visibility.Hidden;
    if (comp.Cost > PlayerShip.Instance.Savings)
        return Visibility.Visible;
    return Visibility.Hidden;
}
```

Any idea why my labels aren't becoming visible when the condition tested in the converter changes after clicking the button? I tried this to no avail:

```
private void btnBuy_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    txtMineralsWarning.GetBindingExpression(TextBlock.VisibilityProperty).UpdateTarget();
    txtCrewWarning.GetBindingExpression(TextBlock.VisibilityProperty).UpdateTarget();
}
```

Comment: Rather than use code behind, you might consider learning how to code in MVVM style using bindings and having a class that handles INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: Your are not passing parameter to your converter, as I can see! You need to pass parameter in your Visibility binding  like this `Visibility="{Binding Path=YourComponent ,Converter={StaticResource NotEnoughMineralsToVisibilityConverter}, UpdateSourceTrigger =PropertyChanged}"`, and add UpdateSourceTrigger at the end! '

Comment: You can try in your button click event call `txtMineralsWarning.UpdateLayout()`

Comment: @ekolis: What is your issue? That the Convert method doesn't get hit when you click on the Button or that it returns the wrong value?

Comment: @mm8 I think the Convert method isn't getting called again when I click the button.

Comment: @ekolis: Did you put a breakpoint in the Convert method to confirm this?

Answer (score 0):

You should do it with MVVM

Working Sample:

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp4.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp4"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Command="{Binding ClickCommand}" Content="Click Me" />
        <TextBlock Text="Label" Visibility="{Binding LabelVisibility}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Code Behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window {
    public MainWindow() {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null) {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        public ICommand ClickCommand => new RelayCommand(arg => DoExecuteClickCommand());

        private void DoExecuteClickCommand() {
            if (LabelVisibility == Visibility.Visible) {
                LabelVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            } else {
                LabelVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
            }
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(LabelVisibility));
        }

        public Visibility LabelVisibility { get; set; }
    }

    public class RelayCommand : ICommand {
        #region Fields

        readonly Action<object> _execute;
        readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;

        #endregion // Fields

        #region Constructors

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a new command that can always execute.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="execute">The execution logic.</param>
        public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute)
            : this(execute, null) {
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a new command.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="execute">The execution logic.</param>
        /// <param name="canExecute">The execution status logic.</param>
        public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute) {
            if (execute == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("execute"); //NOTTOTRANS

            _execute = execute;
            _canExecute = canExecute;
        }

        #endregion // Constructors

        #region ICommand Members

        [DebuggerStepThrough]
        public bool CanExecute(object parameter) {
            return _canExecute == null ? true : _canExecute(parameter);
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged {
            add => CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
            remove => CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter) {
            _execute(parameter);
        }

        #endregion // ICommand Members
    }
```